# How to print a column header that satisfies row and column conditions

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match

I have two columns, one with length and one with weight (columns D and F). I am trying to print for each combination of the two, a value that corresponds to the national percentile (headers on columns M through U).

I need to first match my length (column D) with one in column L. From there, I need to go across the row for the corresponding L value that matches the closest to my weight (column F). Then, I need to print that value's column header in column H, titled "Percentile".

I've included a screen shot of the beginning values but the possible lengths in column L extend to 104 and I have 4432 possible combinations of length and weight (columns D and F).

How can I go about doing this? I imagine it has something to do with index or maybe a vlookup?

[image: Sample data]I would expect the first two values to be 97 and 25. I'm rounding up in each case.

Comment: So to be precise, `11.944` would be closer to 12 then `12.196`. How do you get to `97` as expected output? What exactly are you rounding up?

Comment: Apologies, not rounding up but choosing the larger number when there are two possibilities. It doesn't have to be that way but rather than calculating the difference between 12 and every possible value on row 79, I'm just choosing the larger. 97 comes from the column header; after finding the closest number to 12, I want to print the column header that value falls under.

Comment: I still don't get it, you want to find the number closest to 12, why do you go with `12.196` instead of `11.944`?

Comment: It was chosen arbitrarily because I can't think of how to calculate the difference between all the possibilities on that row in Excel and picking the smallest, so I eyeballed it.

Answer (score 0):

Well.... first of all this will be volatile but you could use:

```
=INDEX($M$1:$U$1,,MATCH(MIN(ABS(INDIRECT("M"&MATCH(D2,$L$1:$L$61,0)&":U"&MATCH(D2,$L$1:$L$61,0))-F2)),ABS(INDIRECT("M"&MATCH(D2,$L$1:$L$61,0)&":U"&MATCH(D2,$L$1:$L$61,0))-F2),0))
```

Enter through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Outcome will be 95 and 10 instead of 97 and 25 since that is really the closest matches!